# minimum steps to re-generate MF fonts

Tags: metafont

I started studying metafont. I created some basics MF, with a single char.

I would like to modify existing font, but I see no 'makefile' that I can just use to tell the system 'just regenerate all the files', even if I altered `romanu.mf` and re-created a PDF via a .TeX file. I want to avoid if possible all the manual command lines.

I tried `mf` and `initexmf` and various command lines but couldn't find such a shortcut. I don't want to edit externally a TTF or OTF, as I think defining fonts with a programming language is great.

any idea?

Comment: don't modify the computer modern sources without changing the file names.

Comment: The basic steps (say to generate cmr10) is `mf cmr10` (which will make the tfm and gf file then gftopk to make pk files. Note you end up with bitmap fonts not ttf or OTF

Comment: @DavidCarlisle why is changing the file name required? for licence or functionality reasons ?

Comment: Licence. It is the one stipulation that Knuth places on his work. Also of course functionality, a major promise of Tex and the computer modern fonts is that it works the same everywhere, and for all time, you can write a document now and process it in a hundred years. That doesn't work if variant forms are produced under the same name.